# From the terminal, how do I determine the date/time for the last time Windows was locked or unlocked?

Tags: windows-10, terminal, batch-file, lock-screen, lock

I press <kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> every time I physically leave my computer, for basic security. When I come back, I enter the short Windows password and press Enter to go back into my desktop. (This is not "logging out" or "logging in".)

Now, I'm trying to determine, from a terminal command, the timestamp for when the machine was last locked in this manner, or when it was last unlocked. It doesn't matter which one; both are equally valuable to me.

(It's going to be used to determine when to send a "sign of life" to my security system.)

Windows 10 Pro. No external software, please. If possible, I'd *prefer* if the solution doesn't use PowerShell either, due to the many hard-to-explain issues with that environment.

The ideal answer would be something like:

```
getlastunlock.exe
```

Which prints:

```
2020-11-17 01:07:04
```

Please tell me there is such a facility in Windows.

Comment: What you want isn’t possible with command prompt, what you want would have been possible with PowerShell, providing you were willing to parse event logs.

Comment: [Here](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/764481-get-logon-off-workstation-lock-unlock-times) is an example of what @Ramhound is getting at.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by processing the output of the `wevtutil` (**W**indows **Ev**en**t** **Util**ity) command. Before we continue, I will agree with Ramhound that PowerShell is the better way to accomplish this.

There are four event IDs that may be relevant to you:

- 7001 is the logon event
- 7002 is the logoff event
- 4800 is the lock event
- 4801 is the unlock event

Below is a Windows [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) that you can run from the command line. You can name it `getlastunlock.bat` and save it in a location that is listed in your [`PATH`](https://ss64.com/nt/path.html) variable. Then you can open the command prompt and run `getlastunlock` to see the results.

### Batch file

```
@ECHO off
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=16 delims=^<" %%a IN (`wevtutil qe System /rd ^| findstr "4800 4801"`) DO (
   CALL:getTime "%%a"
   GOTO:EndLoop
)
:EndLoop
EXIT /b

:getTime
SETLOCAL
:: getTime String [RtnVar]
::             -- String  The string to pull the time from.
::             -- RtnVar  An optional variable to be used to return the time.
SET "s=%~1"
SET "tTime=%s:~24,19%"
SET "time=%tTime:T= %"
ENDLOCAL&IF "%~2" neq "" (set %~2=%time%) ELSE ECHO %time%
EXIT /b
```

### Breakdown

Here is what this script does, step by step:

1. `@ECHO off` tells the batch interpreter to not show you the commands that are being run. By default, you would see the commands exactly as if you were typing them yourself.
2. `FOR /F "usebackq tokens=16 delims=^<" %%a IN (`wevtutil qe System ^| findstr "7001 4801"`) DO (` is a mouthful, so let's break it down further:

   1. [`FOR /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) is a loop command. It takes some input and loops through each line of it.
   2. `usebackq` uses the alternate quoting style of the input to make it easier to pass in commands containing quotation marks.
   3. `tokens=16` means we only want the 16th item in the line.
   4. `delims=^<` means we want to split each line into separate items by the `<` character. The output of `wevutil` is in XML format, which uses `<elements>` to store information. `wevutil` allows output in text, too, but that would be harder to parse.
   5. `%%a` defines the variable name of the 16th item in the line to be used later.
   6. `IN` means "use the following command to get the output to loop through.
   7. `` (`wevtutil qe System /rd ^| findstr "4800 4801"`) `` is the command which returns the output we want to loop through.

      1. `wevtutil qe System /rd` means we want to export the contents of the `System` event log, in reverse chronological order (newest first).
      2. `^|` is the "pipe character", escaped. That is, the output of `wevtutil` will be "piped into" or used as input for the next command. We "escape" the `|` character with the `^` character to tell the batch interpreter not to use the `|` to split the whole line, but just these two commands.
      3. `findstr "4800 4801"` takes the output of `wevtutil` and searches for lines containing `4800` and `4801`, our lock and unlock events. You can change this to whatever event IDs you want.
   8. `DO` means run the following commands on every line of the output.
3. `CALL:getTime "%%a"` sends the 16th item on the current line to the `getTime` subroutine.
4. `GOTO:EndLoop` exits the loop so that it only runs once, meaning it will only process the most recent relevant result. [`GOTO`](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html) is different from [`CALL`](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) in that when the subroutine ends, the script ends. If it were a `CALL`, then the subroutine ending would return the script to the line after this one.
5. `:EndLoop` defines a label we can call using `GOTO`.
6. `EXIT /b` tells the command interpreter to exit the batch file here. Everything after this line should be subroutines which are called from within the code above.
7. `:getTime` defines the name of the subroutine.
8. `SETLOCAL` defines a local context, meaning any environment variables set in this context won't be passed back to the rest of the batch file.
9. `SET "s=%~1"` sets the input to the subroutine into the `s` variable.
10. `SET "tTime=%s:~24,19%"` gets the T delimited, [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted time from the `s` variable.
11. `SET "time=%tTime:T= %"` replaces the T with a space to give you the format you wanted.
12. `ENDLOCAL&IF "%~2" neq "" (set %~2=%time%) ELSE ECHO %time%` takes advantage of the full line processing of the command interpreter to both end the local context *and* pass a variable out of it (the time).
13. `EXIT /b` here tells the command interpreter that the subroutine has ended and to return back to processing in the original location.

### References

- [Path variable - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/path.html)
- [For /f command - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- [Findstr command - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [Call command and subroutines - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html)
- [Goto command - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)
- [Setlocal command - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)
- [Exit command - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/exit.html)
- [ISO 8601 - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)